# Check if 'Access to my location' is enabled - Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I have an android app that uses location. But I noticed that if users disable the 'Access to my location' in Settings > Location access, nothing works anymore. How can I check that it's enabled?
In case it's disabled, how to open those settings from my app?

Thanks

**SOLVED :**

```
String locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if (locationProviders == null || locationProviders.equals("")) {
    ...
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be this will be useful
check this site it discusses about location service

http://www.scotthelme.co.uk/android-location-services/

Comment: Ok it seems to be Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED); thansk, any idea how to open it from my app?

Answer (score 8):

You can check it like that:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) // Return a boolean
```

EDIT:

If you want to check the network provider:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) // Return a boolean
```

EDIT 2:

If you want to open the settings, you can use this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
```

Comment: You can too check the availability of the network provider (replace `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` by `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER`).

Comment: If you want Wifi use the NETWORK provider. Have a look at docs and official Android articles, such as: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html (and note there is newer stuff now too, via Google Play Services, like the fused provider: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html.

Comment: Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED); works better as it provides every provider available

Comment: Thanks Charlie Collings, I'll have a look at fused provider

Comment: I never used `Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);` but I will try it. In addition, I put a clue to open the location source settings.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to do that without using `Settings.Secure` and without scanning all location providers would be to do:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
int providersCount = locationManager.getProviders(true).size(); // Listing enabled providers only
if (providersCount == 0) {
    // No location providers at all, location is off
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems the using of `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED` is deprecated since API 19.

A new way to do that would be:

```
int locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(
    getContentResolver(),
    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
    Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF // Default value if not found
);

if (locationMode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF) {
    // Location is off
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to check location,
1-using GPS
2-using network provider
its better to check both service are enabled or not.For that use this method :)

```
public boolean checkServices(){
    //check location service
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) &&
            locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont know why some one gives me -1 for this...this solution is works for me and im using it.if the solution didnt work with you try another solution dont mark as -1 idiot,