# Enable google location services intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-location, android-settings

is it possible to take the user to Settings -> Location using intent, so he would be able to enable the app go get the device location?

This is the screen I want to go to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Intent intent= new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Any idea how can I check if the location is enabled?

Comment: something similar to this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150613/check-if-access-to-my-location-is-enabled-android)